# How do I stop my application from storing sent sms in default android message application?

Tags: android, smsmanager

Sorry if this has been answered but I can't find it anywhere and I've googled for 2 days now for the answer.

I am creating a application that can send a text message from a predefined list of numbers. When I send the messages they are getting stored in the default message application. Is there a way that I can stop this from happening, because if the user send 300 messages, they're going to get 300 names and what was sent in their default message application.

The code I'm using is:

```
public void sendMessage(String number, ArrayList<String> message) {
    String _messageNumber = number;
    ArrayList<String> messageText =  message;

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(_messageNumber, null, messageText, null, null);

}d
```

Comment: Cant really see where you are using threads ... your question is not really clear to me.

Comment: And your code can be resumed in 1 line:
    public void sendMessage(String number, ArrayList<String> message) {
        SmsManager.getDefault().sendMultipartTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
    }

Comment: When I said threads I meant entries in the normal sms app. If my user wants to send a sms to 300 people, the user will get 300 entries in the normal sms app.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't [seem possible anymore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29): 
"Note: Beginning with Android 4.4 (API level 19), if and only if an app is not selected as the default SMS app, the system automatically writes messages sent using this method to the SMS Provider (the default SMS app is always responsible for writing its sent messages to the SMS Provider)."

Comment: I believe this only applies to text sms, not port based sms.  Any app that needs to send private smses to an app on another phone ought to use port based.  Otherwise IMO it should be posted to the sms database

Answer (score 0):

Technically default message application doesn't store anything. It just reads messages from database of your mobile. So, it blindly reads all the messages and display it to you. You cant stop the app doing that. So, one way is make your own message database. Just sent the messages to whom ever you want. Later copy whole data to your custom database and delete those messages from default database.